# SharePoint Auto number

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have library with a few lookup columns that looks up data in the same site. The lookup columns are Category, Type, Counter Party.

I want to create a unique number using these metadata. for Example: Cat/Type/CounterParty/ID.
What I have done is create a workflow that gets this info and adds it to "text" columns I created. 
I then use a calculated column to add Cat/Type/CounterParty/ID which works perfectly.

The question I have is:
When the Cat/Type/CounterParty is the same I want the number to start with 001 and then increase from there. For example: CAT/TYPE/CP/001, CAT/TYPE/CP/002 ... if one of the combinations change it must start at 001 again eg. CAT!!/TYPE/CP/001, CAT!!/TYPE/CP/002. The ID is not working for me. Will this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better to implement your own Custom Document ID Provider. This will lookup the (lookup) values.
Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521589(v=office.14).aspx for a example or http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-sharepoint-server-2010-creating-a-custom-document-id-provider

The biggest challange will be your choice where to maintain the list if previously generated document id's.